# linq excluding one result set from another

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

In my first line of code I am getting all available forms.

In the second line of code I'm getting all signed forms.

```
  IEnumerable<ClinicForm> AllForms = db.ClinicForms.Where
                                     (d => d.ClinicId == clinicId);

  var SignedForms = db.SignedForms.Where
                    (d => d.FormSigned == d.ClinicForm.Id && d.PatientId==patientId);
```

Both of these lines of code work fine, but what I'm trying to do is get the list of all forms excluding the any of the signed forms.

I've made several attempts here.

```
var test = from c in AllForms
           where !SignedForms.Contains(c.FormName)
           select c;
```

This attempt results in an error:
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(SDatabaseLibrary.SignedForm)' has some invalid arguments

My second attempt:

```
var test2 = from y in AllForms
            where !(from x in SignedForms
            where x.FormSigned==x.ClinicForm.Id && x.PatientId==patientId
                  select x.ClinicForm).Contains(y.Id)
                  select y;
```

Error   5   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

No doubt I am casting something wrong, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final working solution, took a lot of playing with to get it working

```
var AllForms = db.ClinicForms.Where(d => d.ClinicId == clinicId);

var SignedForms = AllForms.Where(d => d.SignedForm.FormSigned == d.Id
                                 && d.SignedForm.PatientId == patientId);


var res = AllForms.Except(SignedForms);
```